# Windows won't dual boot, os-prober can't find Windows and Windows BSOD!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I resized a linux data partition and now windows7 won't boot, I just get a quick flash of a BSOD

I've run boot-repair a many times and this is the latest output:

http://paste2.org/L2WkzB62

If I manually install the option for windows I can boot it but get the BSOD again.

As can be seen from the pastebin Windows is not detected by os-prober yet the partition seems to be fine.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'll be most appreciative.